# How to write a composed function using Ramda compose?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

How to modify the zComposedFn function so that the output of both z and zComposedOutput is same?

```js
const R = require('ramda');

let f1 = R.curry((p1, p2, p3) => {
    let result = {
        n1: p1,
        n2: p2,
        n3: p3
    };
    return result;
}
);

let x = f1(1, 2, 3);
let y = f1(1, 2, x);
let z = f1(1, x , y);

console.log(z);

let zComposedFn = R.compose(f1);

let input = [1,2,3];
let zComposedOutput = zComposedFn(...input);

console.log(zComposedOutput);
```

The goal is to create some metric calculation functions having the same signature and output type but different implementation.

```
const MetricFn = (m,f,a) => {<to be implemented using switch case on m> return b}

m : name of metric as string
f : Array of functions utilizing  input data objects
a : input data object
```

example:

There is a financial dashboard, which receives the input data as (1,2,3). The dashboard displays the metric1, metric2 and metric3 calculated as below:

```
metric1 = MetricFn('metric1',[f1])(1,2,3);
metric2 = MetricFn('metric2',[f1, f2])(1,2,3);
metric3 = MetricFn('metric3',[f1, f2, f3])(1,2,3);
```

I am wondering on how to create the structure of MetricFn.

Comment: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose
Note: The rightmost function may have any arity; the remaining functions must be unary.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what a function for `metric3` might look like for example?  I'm still confused about how each metric acts and how they're tied to `f1`, `f2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can make very little sense out of your function.  And I don't see anything that Ramda offers to help.  While I'm a Ramda author, I don't always recall every function, but it seems unlikely.

Your requirements looks vaguely like the use of `chain` with functions, where `chain(f, g) ~~> x => f(g(x))(x)`.  But it's only a vague connection, and I can't see how to use chain to do what you are trying to do.

Is there an underlying problem you're trying to solve that we might be able to help with?

Here is a trivial implementation, but it's mostly just restating your code without the intermediate variables:

```
const foo = curry((f, a, b, c) => f(a, f(a, b, c), f(a, b, f(a, b, c))))
foo(f1)(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added the use case. Requesting for some help in creating the "MetricFn" function.

Comment: It's still fairly unclear to me.  See my comment on the question.